# Calling methods from PCL to android - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can I call method defined in my `PCL` project to `Android` project ?

I have a method `DoWork()` defined in my PCL and I want this method to continuously be run in a service defined in my android project as follows:

```
public class BroadcastService : Service
{
    IBinder mBinder;


    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

        Toast.MakeText(this, "BroadcastService is running ", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var counter = new Counter();
            counter.DoWork().Wait();
        });

        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;

    }
```

The toast is appearing.
However, the `DoWork()` is not running. Can someone enlighten what is wrong please?

The full method signature for `DoWork()` :

```
 private async void DoWork()
        {
       StartDetect();

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), () =>
                {
                    _foundTags = _truck.GetAvailableTrucks();


                    DoWork();


                });
        }
```

Comment: What is the full method signature of `DoWork()`?

Comment: @SushiHangover : I have added the full method signature in the edits above. 

My logic is implemented in the android project and I have accessed same through dependency service.  

Now to make the background service run the code, should I call the call directly within the android project or through the PCL ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a MessagingCenter. You can try something like this

public class BroadcastService : Service
{
    IBinder mBinder;

```
[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{

    Toast.MakeText(this, "BroadcastService is running ", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dowork");


    base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;

}
```

and in your PCL project

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "dowork", (sender) =>
        {
            // Do something here

        });
        // Handle when your app starts
    }
```

Comment: Normally, my app is launched automatically on device boot up, without user intervention of launching the app manually. 

So there is a receiver that starts the `BroadcastService` once the device is boot up. Could you please advise where should I put this `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "dowork", (sender) =>` ?

Comment: Is your app a Xamarin Forms app? You can add it in OnStart method (like the example), or in OnAppearing method in the page you would like to execute the "work"

Comment: Yes my app is based on the XF. The `work` should be executed in background. The app is a detection of bluetooth tags and send this information to a remote web service. Henceforth, I want this app to be launched automatically on device bootup and run in background. I don't think the OnStart method will achieve this. Any advise ?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to execute the "work" on PCL side... Can't you send your Bluetooth tags info directly from Android prj?

Comment: Hmm yes I can. But as initially the code was on PCL. and I even used some dependency services. 

But I'm thinking while the app is running in background, I want another thread of the app to run if I launch the app manually. Is this possible ? or maybe I'm thinking it wrongly.

Comment: I don't understand. Your BroadcastService works in background and foreground. You should be able to read always your tags. In Android prj, when you receive some data, call your webservice. It should be enough

Comment: Sorry to disturb again. Does the work of a background service run a different thread?

Comment: What if I launch the app manually from the screen while the background service is running ? The same codes will be invoked. Won't there by any conflict ?